# Single linked list, practice implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, c++14

I am preparing for some interviews and I trying to just write a basic single linked list quickly. The code compiles fine but nothing seems to print and I am not sure why.

This is what I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct Node {
    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next = nullptr;

     Node(const int& x, std::unique_ptr<Node>&& p = nullptr)
        : data(x)
        , next(std::move(p)) {}

};
std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
Node* tail;

void print() {
    auto temp = head.get();
    while (temp) {
        std::cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next.get();
    }
    std::cout << "\t";
}

void push_back(const int& theData) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> newNode = std::make_unique<Node>(theData);

    if (!head) {
        newNode = std::move(head);
        tail = head.get();
    }
    else {
        tail->next = std::move(newNode);
        tail = tail->next.get();
    }
}

int main() {

    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    push_back(2);
    push_back(4);
    push_back(6);
    print();


    std::cin.get();

}
```

This should print 2 4 6 but it does not print anything. Any idea why?

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: `std::move`ing either `int` or `const int&` is exactly the same as passing a simple, copied `int`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I haven't learned how to use break points that well.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Knowing how to use the debugger is a pretty essential skill for every programmer. What do you plan to tell in the interview, if they're going to ask about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updaing your `head` in `push_back()`. Instead of

```
if (!head) { newNode = std::move(head); ... }
```

you should be doing

```
if (!head) {head = std::move(newNode); ... }
```